# How to theme Options of select box

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have been searching everywhere, but havent found a solution yet.

I need to know how to theme a option list of a select box. In my wordpress site im using this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/ .

This plugin creates a dropdown list of taxonomy using "select" and "option" tag.

How do i add my own css to this  tag?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming by "theme" you mean style the select with CSS. First off, selects aren't the simplest things to style, there are limits unless you get into javascript. But I would check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript

Comment: you'd be better of creating custom select or using some plugins...

Comment: Yea i meant style it. Thanks ill look into the link that you shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can style it. Here's the raw sketch I've exctracted:

**[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/VrSN8/5/)**

`select` has an ID of `some-filter` and htis field is customized using the `some-filter` ID in the CSS.

You can, for example, set custom dropdown-arrows, or background, or box-shadow, or anythying you'd like.

However, there are some hacks for Firefox and IE, they are marked in the CSS code. If it hadn' been for them, the default `dropdown` arrow of the IE and FF would have been displayed.

Play with the fiddle.